# I have some problem with the shortest path length of a tree (a connected graph with n vertices, n-1 edges)

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path

Given a connected undirected graph with n vertices, n-1 edges. Find a path from 1 vertex, go through exactly n-k+1 other vertices and return to the starting vertex with the shortest path length.
And each edge has the positive weight and k <= min(20, n-1), n <= 1e5

I think that I can use Dijikstra's Algorithm and some properties of Hamilton cycle. Then I realize Eulerian cycle is visiting each vertices once.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Are your graph links directed or undirected?

Comment: @ravenspoint It is undirected one

Comment: What about visiting the same node twice?

Comment: @ravenspoint You can visit the same note as many time as you like, but the path length must be shortest and you must visit n-k+1 nodes

Comment: OK, then my answer will give you what you want.

Comment: If you visit the same node, does it get counted twice?

Comment: @Neil Yes, it does.

Comment: What prevents you from going back and forth on the minimum edge?

Answer (score 0):

For an undirected graph and permission to transit the same link twice this algorithm will provide the result.

- Run Dijsktra.  This will give you the paths from the starting node to every other node.
- Find all paths with ( n - k + 1 ) / 2 nodes visited.
- Select from those paths the shortest.
- Add to path the path nodes in reverse order, getting back to starting node.

Note: you will have to decide what to do if n - k + 1 is odd.